# position an element with respect to a particular point of an image in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

What I want to do is position an element (a coloured `UIView` that I use as a background) to my storyboard so that it starts at the middle of an `ImageField` and fills everything till the bottom of the screen. I'm using xcode7 and swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can align the bottom of your UIView and UIImageView, and keep the height of your UIView as half of that of UIImageView.

Or if you want the view to go till the bottom, you can do it all in storyboard by adding another view that extends from the bottom of the UIImageView to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: and how can I make sure that it will expand down till the bottom of the screen?

Comment: @MarinosK Updated the answer to match the requirements